# subprocess.Popen tries to write to nonexistent pipe

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Why doesn't the following work?

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('cmd.exe', shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
```

The output I get is the following:

```
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

After which the process terminates without an error. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Is that your complete program? Because you seem to be missing `process.communicate()`.

Comment: Output is the same with process.communicate() and variants.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running windows 10 and have the same problem. The error goes away for me if I set stdout and stderr to the same value. Try setting them both to subprocess.PIPE instead of just stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["echo", "Hello, world!"], shell=True)
```

This uses the default stdout and stderr, instead of creating a PIPE.

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.