# Why I can't use `Stdio::piped()` with windows `cmd.exe` in Rust?

Tags: windows, cmd, rust, process

When I try  to start `cmd.exe` by the following code:

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};
use std::io::{BufRead, Write, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let mut child_cmd = Command::new("cmd.exe")  
        // seems it work well with `/bin/bash` in Linux
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())   // Error emitted here. 
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();   
    // do sth. else
}
```

I want to redirect the output to pipeline, but it always report `The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe`; when I removed `.stdout(Stdio::piped())`, no errors thrown. Why does this happen?

Comment: Going out on a limb here, but does [piping `stderr` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60255186/4038191) work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EvilTak's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68927669/why-i-cant-use-stdiopiped-with-windows-cmd-exe-in-rust#comment121817236_68927669) is spot on. When you redirect STDOUT to a pipe, you'll also have to redirect STDERR to a pipe. The following code no longer errors out:

```rust
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut child_cmd = Command::new("cmd.exe")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped())  // Required when redirecting stdout
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();
    // do sth. else
}
```

While that fixes the immediate issue, I'm not sure what actually causes it. Looking at the [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) function and the [STARTUPINFOW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure it accepts, it looks as though standard I/O redirection is an all-or-nothing option, designated by the `STARTF_USESTDHANDLES` flag.

The fact that [Python exhibits the same behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18796397/1889329) suggests that this is in fact a peculiarity of either the Windows API or *cmd.exe*'s implementation.

Either way, I have not done any extensive research to figure out what exactly is going on here.